# Extruder feeding excessive material

Tags: extruder

I've been trying to print concrete using a 7mm nozzle. The issue I'm facing is my extruder is pushing too much material in the print head and material can't be extruded at the same rate from the nozzle while printing. As a result, more material gets accumulated in the print head and the tube gets disconnected from the print head like this in the picture. I have calibrated the E-steps, and also reduced the flow rate. Can anyone suggest me what settings I need to adjust to fix this issue? Thanks.[image]

[image]

Comment: What printer is it? And what filament you are using?  What temperatures?

Comment: Uncommon setup. Interesting. @Mołot the 'filament' is concrete (beton). The nozzle is not -0.7mm but 7mm.

Comment: @Souvik can you share more information about what printer this is, what slicer and slicer settings you are using, how does the model look? What is your question? 'Why are my lines not straight?', 'Why is the extruder feeding excessive material?'. Please reflect that in the title. Keep in mind that concrete printing is unfamiliar to most users, the material (properties) are entirely different. I don't know much about it either but my initial guess would be that the composition of your concrete is too fluid? Can you share information about what mixture and composition of concrete you are use?

Comment: @BobOrtiz I'm using a Stoneflower multimaterial 3D printer and using Cura 5.2.1 for slicing the hollow square model. I'm using a 7mm nozzle. In cura, I used filament diameter (7 and 2.5mm) and calculated the E-steps value according to these numbers. If I use 2.5mm dia then the E-steps is 67.67, and if I use 7mm then it 530.53 steps/mm. I also changed the flow rate from 100 to 80 and 50%. Nothing worked. The extruder is pushing a lot of material and the material can't be extruded at the same rate. So, should I change the e-step value as I'm using a new motor now with higher torque than before.

Comment: @BobOrtiz For the concrete mix, yes it's a little bit more flowable compared to conventional concrete. It uses Cement, Silica Fume, Sand, Fly ash, Water, Superplasticizer, and Viscosity modifying agents. I have printed with this composition before. After changing the motor and printhead these issues arise. The previous motor had a torque of 48 Ncm and the new one has 55 Ncm. Could this be a potential issue?